# Is the celebration of salvation affected by the deaths of those who were not saved?

Tags: blessing, hagomel, parties-celebrations

There is a obligation to [thank G-d](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/115308/jewish/The-Laws-of-the-Blessing-of-Thanksgiving.htm)  when one is saved from a life-threatening situation. Some have a custom to [publicly celebrate, often with a festive meal](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/680369/jewish/What-is-the-source-for-the-custom-of-making-a-thanksgiving-feast.htm). Some even make it a [yearly occurrence](http://www.chabad.org/search/keyword_cdo/kid/8971/jewish/Tammuz-12-13.htm).

What happens when one is saved from a tragedy where other people were not as fortunate. Does this affect the celebration. For example, does one forgo the festive meal? Maybe only publicly?

Are there some kind of guidelines about how to celebrate in such a circumstance.

One example I can think of is someone who survived the collapse of the World Trade Center buildings on September 11, 2001. How is his celebration halachically affected by the deaths of others while he was saved?

Comment: We celebrate Pesach even though many (most) didn't make it. We celebrate Chanuka even though many died in battle.

Comment: @ShmuelBrin TTBOMK we don't celebrate those who survived the Crusades or Holocaust.

Comment: Menachem, is this about saying the bracha in such a case, or having celebratory meals/parties? (I'm asking mainly because of your tags.)

Comment: @DoubleAA: I think more the celebration, since it appears that the blessing is an obligation, while the celebratory meal is a custom. I could be wrong.

Comment: @ShmuelBrin: I'm focusing more on those who survived themselves, as opposed to us commemorating it later. Perhaps 12 Tammuz was a bad example to give since it is celebrated worldwide, but the Previous Rebbe also celebrated it himself (he also referred to it as a day of redemption for every Jew). It was the example I thought of when I wrote the question.